# Snowflake Node Lambda Connection Hangs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the snowflake node driver to connect to a DB. When running the connector from a local server I have no issues. However, when I try the same function running in lambda I can't seem to connect. There are no errors, exceptions, or timeouts... just nothing. Here is the code I'm using per their documentation.

```
var snowflake = require("snowflake-sdk");
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: "****",
  username: "******",
  password: "******",
});

connect(connection);

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda!"),
};
return response;

function connect(connection) {
  console.log("in connection");
  let connection_ID;
  try {
    connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to connect: " + err);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to Snowflake");
        // Optional: store the connection ID.
        connection_ID = conn.getId();
      }
      console.log(connection_ID);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

For clarity, my lambda has no issues connecting to other API's, and is not running behind a VPC.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be log messages. Is there anything in cloudwatch?

Comment: There is literally nothing in cloudwatch, I even added a log in the function to make sure the function itself was called and it is... but the snowflake connections does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not selected any VPC for your lambda function, it will use the default VPC of the region.
Can you select a VPC, which has access to the snowflake public endpoints and check.
If still an issue, please post the Cloud watch logs, it should give a clue.
You can also check on snowflake History page, if you get any Client-side connection request from the lambda or not.

Comment: There isn't anything in the cloudwatch logs which is why this is so puzzling, I can also confirm that in the snowflake history page I'm not seeing any attempts from lambda.
Can you tell me how to use the vpc to access snowflake public endpoints? I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. This behavior occurs due to how the SDK is written, it is actually using promises and asynchronous calls. This is not intuitive from the documentation, which makes the code look like it was written to behave synchronously.

I stumbled across this post David Szmolka while investigating the issue- https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/464#issuecomment-1495923219

It has great reference code on how to show how to chain the promises together to arrive a synchronous behavior. The connectToSnoflake usage below comes from it.

```
var snowflake = require("snowflake-sdk");
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: "****",
  username: "******",
  password: "******",
});


await connectToSnoflake(connection)
        .then( (conn) => {
          let connection_ID = conn.getId();;
          console.log('connection_ID ', connection_ID)
        } );

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify("Hello from Lambda!"),
};
return response;


async function connectToSnoflake(connection) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      connection.connect( (err, conn) => {
        try {
          if (err) {
              console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
              reject(err)
          }
          console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
          resolve(conn)
        }catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
  })
}
```